# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent create

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables:

**user:**

> id, username, password

**customers:**

> id, user_id, fullname, address

In my CustomerController.php, store() function
I need to create user first and then customer with user_id.

```
Customer::create($request->all());
```

is inserting the customer data but without user_id

Is there anyway to add user and customer at once using Eloquent?

My **User** model is:

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
    public function customers(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Customer', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Customer model

```
class Customer extends Model {
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to wrap your operation in a Gateway pattern (also known as Service Pattern, but differ from Laravel Service Provider concept).

Comment: Yes, we all want to be lazy! :) And write just `$customer->save()` and expect that new user is saved with customers' data.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a transaction, to make sure both or none are saved.

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    $customer = new Customer($request->only(['fullname', 'address']));
    $user = User::create($request->only(['username', 'password']));
    $user->customers()->save($customer);
});
```

Comment: Pawel: This is working fine. (Y) just has to change DB::transaction(function ()  use ($request){ . But, this is not the way of Eloquent, right?

Comment: The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models) has an example of saving related objects but its using find instead of creating the parent. Transaction is just making sure you save both or none in case something goes wrong. You could overwrite the save method but I think this is simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the model's creating/created events and act perform some prerequisite actions then. This is very useful for creating related models and configuring anything before hand. See the documentation on model events here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events